# Solving consumer producer concurrency issue with SynchronousQueue. Fairness property not working

Tags: java, android, multithreading, blockingqueue

I am having a issue debugging my SynchronousQueue. its in android studio but should not matter its java code.  I am passing in true to the constructor of SynchronousQueue so its "fair" meaning its a fifo queue.  But its not obeying the rules, its still letting the consumer print first and the producer after. The second issue i have is i want these threads to never die, do you think i should use a while loop on the producer and the consumer thread and let them keep "producing and consuming" each other ?

here is my simple code:

```
   package com.example.android.floatingactionbuttonbasic;


import java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue;

import trikita.log.Log;


public class SynchronousQueueDemo {


    public SynchronousQueueDemo() {
    }


    public void startDemo() {
        final SynchronousQueue<String> queue = new SynchronousQueue<String>(true);

        Thread producer = new Thread("PRODUCER") {
            public void run() {
                String event = "FOUR";
                try {
                    queue.put(event); // thread will block here
                   Log.v("myapp","published event:", Thread
                           .currentThread().getName(), event);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        };

        producer.start(); // starting publisher thread

        Thread consumer = new Thread("CONSUMER") {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    String event = queue.take(); // thread will block here
                    Log.v("myapp","consumed event:", Thread
                            .currentThread().getName(), event);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        };

        consumer.start(); // starting consumer thread

    }

}
```

to start the threads i simple call  `new SynchronousQueueDemo().startDemo();`

The logs always look like this no matter what i pass to synchronousQueue constructor to be "fair":

```
/SynchronousQueueDemo$2$override(26747): myapp  consumed event: CONSUMER    FOUR
V/SynchronousQueueDemo$1$override(26747): myapp published event:PRODUCER    FOUR
```

Checking the [docs here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/SynchronousQueue.html), it says the following:

> public SynchronousQueue(boolean fair)
>   Creates a SynchronousQueue with the specified fairness policy.
>   Parameters:
>   fair - if true, waiting threads contend in FIFO order for access; otherwise the order is unspecified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The fairness policy relates to the order in which the queue is read.  The order of execution for a producer/consumer is for the consumer to take(), releasing the producer (which was blocking on put()).  Set fairness=true if the order of consumption is important.
2. If you want to keep the threads alive, have a loop condition which behaves well when interrupted (see below).  Presumably you want to put a Thread.sleep() in the Producer, to limit the rate at which events are produced.

   ```
   public void run() {
       boolean interrupted = false;
       while (!interrupted) {
           try {
                // or sleep, then queue.put(event)
                queue.take(event); 
           } catch (InterruptedException e) {
               interrupted = true;;
           }
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: interrupted will always be false in this case

Comment: How do you mean?  The thread stop policy is to interrupt(); which will then set interrupted=true.  Please explain and I will correct.  Thank you.

Comment: yeah sorry..my bad..got a little confused here.

Answer (score 1):

SynchronousQueue work on a simple concept. You can only produce if you have a consumer.

1) Now if you start doing `queue.put()` without any `queue.take()`, the thread will  block there. So any soon as you have `queue.take()`, the Producer thread will be unblocked.

2) Similarly if you start doing `queue.take()` it will block until there is a producer. So once you have `queue.put()`, the Consumer Thread will be blocked.

So as soon as `queue.take()` is executed, both Producer and Consumer threads are unblocked. But you do realize that Producer and Consumer are both running in seperate threads. So any of the messages you put after the blocking calls can be executed. In my case the order of the output was this. Producer was getting printed first.

**V/SynchronousQueueDemo$1$override(26747): myapp published event:PRODUCER    FOUR
/SynchronousQueueDemo$2$override(26747): myapp  consumed event: CONSUMER    FOUR**